# Cannot implicitly convert type 'decimal' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have this code in a shopping cart I am creating but I am receiving the error shown in the title.The error is showing up on this line:

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer? can you please explain where this would be done? thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just call `ToString` to get a string representation of the decimal value:

```
order.Total = orderTotal.ToString("G");
```

Although I don't see why you would store the member `Total` as a `string` and not as a `decimal` too.

Comment: hi thanks for the advice, where would it need to be changed to change total to decimal rather than a string

Comment: @user1300580: In the second class you posted (class `Order`), just change the type of `Total` from `string` to `decimal`.

Comment: works a treat, thanks, i was obviously looking in the wrong area. "Beginners mistake"

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the `Order` class has a `Total` property that's a string. Check the class definition for `Order`. If that's the case, I'd recommend changing the `Total` data type to a decimal, because having a currency value represented as a string doesn't make sense. `decimal` makes more sense.

Answer (score 0):

How is your Order  class looks like ? What is the type of the Property called `Total` ? It looks like it is a string type. Here you are trying to set decimal value to a string type That is y you are getting that error. So you need to convert decimal to string before assigning it to a string varaiable. Use the `toString()` method.

```
order.Total = orderTotal.ToString();
```

As Tudor already mentioned, It is better to use Total as a decimal property as it will be easy for you to do all mathematical operations. You dont need to convert it to decimal  format every time you want to do an arithmetical operation and convert it again back to string

Comment: @user1300580: Read the second para of my answer. It is a better idea to make it as decimal

Answer (score 0):

Change the type of `Order.Total` to Decimal.  The data type Decimal does not automatically convert to string (and visa-versa) which is why you're getting an error, plus, any subsequent calls to `Order.Total` would be string related, so you would not be able to use operators like `Order.Total +=`

Also note that any binding convenience like a DataTable's 'format' property would be ignored because the underlying architecture won't call string.ToString(format).

Comment: where are you suggesting this change takes place? Do you mean the same places as people who have answered above

Comment: @user1300580 - make the change in the 'Order' class.  Do not use 'orderTotal.ToString()' because that would be considered a hack to satisfy the model.